# Migrating database with views trough phpMyAdmin causes error in second host

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, migration, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate a database which contains some views and I'm doing trough phpMyAdmin export feature. MySQL version on servers are:

- Server to migrate: Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
- Server from migrate: Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

This is the error I can see trough Apache logs:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'v.id' in
>   'field list',

I just export from one side and import in the other side, what I miss? What can cause the error?

PS: The PHP application at both sides are the same, any advice

Comment: This is not a programming problem. It's system administration problem, and you should hire an expert to fix this for you rather than ask at a website where we discuss **programming problems**.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?